# No such property: geometry when updating feature in openlayers 3 - Geoserver

Tags: ajax, postgresql, openlayers-3, geoserver

I am working on a webmapping app with Openlayers 3, Postgresql and Geoserver 2.8, I want to make a WFS-T transactions for drawing and updating so I followed this steps https://medium.com/@goldrydigital/wfs-t-with-openlayers-3-16-6fb6a820ac58
Here is my modification code :

```
var dirty = {};
select.getFeatures().on('add', function(e) {
    e.element.on('change', function(e) {
        dirty[e.target.getId()] = true;
    });
});
var clone;
select.getFeatures().on('remove', function(e) {
    var f = e.element;
    if (dirty[f.getId()]){
        delete dirty[f.getId()];
        featureProperties = f.getProperties();
        delete featureProperties.boundedBy;
        clone = new ol.Feature(featureProperties);
        clone.setId(f.getId());
        clone.setGeometryName("the_geom");
    }
});

var node = formatwfs.writeTransaction(null, [clone], null, {
            featureNS: "myNameSpace",
            featureType: "myLayer"
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
            data: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node),
            contentType: 'text/xml',
            success: function(data) {
                alert((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(data));
            },
            error: function(e) {
                var errorMsg = e? (e.status + ' ' + e.statusText) : "";
                alert('Error saving this feature to GeoServer.<br><br>'
                + errorMsg);
            },
            context: this
        });
```

the drawing part works fine but for the updating I get an error:

```
<ows:ExceptionText>No such property: geometry</ows:ExceptionText>
```

the geometry column in my table and layer is "the_geom" so I double check it on my code with setGeometryName("the_geom") but yet when I make the AJAX call I get the error above.

The first thing that came to my mind is to change the geometry column name in my postgresql table to geometry and republish the layer in geoserver, but I want to know first if there is any less obedient solution for this, thanks in advance

After changing the geometry column name in postgresql to "geometry" I get now another error :

```
<ows:ExceptionText>java.lang.NullPointerException</ows:ExceptionText>
```

Comment: Thanks for using my WFS-T example. I have since updated the post for OL 3.16. There is also jsFiddle with the complete working example. http://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/13Lwsfmf/

Comment: @DennisBauszus and Thank you for the helpful tutorial, great work, a lot of people are working with your code example

Comment: @DennisBauszus link broken can you update ?

Comment: something odd happening on my jsfiddle. seems the original link is dead but has multiplied into two different fiddles. you can try https://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/x3j1pkq7/ or https://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/h7mk0jpt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the geometry column name into "geometry" and after that the error relative to the Java null pointer came, then I found out that the XML code generated was wrong and needs to be modified for it refers to a wrong typeName **feature:myLayer** while it should be **myNameSpace:myLayer** for this one all I had to do was to replace it with Javascript :

```
var str=new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node);
var data=str.replace("feature:myLayer","myNameSpace:myLayer");
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Hicham Zouarhi's solution you can also change geometry type like this:

```
//Change feature name
const find_feature = `feature:${layerName}`;
const re_feature = new RegExp(find_feature, "g");

//Change feature geometry column
const find_geometry = `<Property><Name>geometry</Name>`;
const re_geometry = new RegExp(find_geometry, "g");

const payload = xs.serializeToString(formatWFS.writeTransaction(null, f, null, formatGML))
 .replace(re_feature, `Bugra:${layerName}`)
 .replace(re_geometry, `<Property><Name>${layerGeometryColumn}</Name>`);
```